# Skip [ScriptIgnore] just once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, javascriptserializer, scriptignore

Environment for this situation:

asp.net mvc 3

c#

Entity Framework 4.3.1

JavaScriptSerializer

I have come across a situation where it would be nice to include a field which has been marked up as `[ScriptIgnore]`. The field, if left without the attribute, would constitute a circular reference and cause an exception to be thrown. The reason is something similar to this:

```
public class Foo
{
 public int FooId { get; set; }

 [ScriptIgnore]
 public virtual Collection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
 public int BarId { get; set; }
 public int FooId { get; set; }
 public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

So you can see here, a `Foo` can have many associated `Bars`. And a `Bar` has an associated `Foo`.

Back to the situation. I am loading this association in a controller using an include statement:

```
.Include( foo => foo.Bars );
```

There are no errors thrown because include is not affected by the `[ScriptIgnore]` annotation. Upon debug, the association is properly constructed when inspected. There is a list of `foos`, and each `foo` has an associated list of `Bars`.

Now I want to serialize this constructed list. I have a view model that gets filled with data, it looks like this:

```
public class FooView
{
 public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

 public string AsJson()
 {
  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  return serializer.Serialize(this);
 }
}
```

So I pass this viewmodel into the view and serialize it:

```
@model FooView
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fooViewModel = @( Html.Raw( Model.AsJson() ) );
</script>
```

No exceptions are thrown, however, the serialization properly skips the field (`Bars`) marked with `[ScriptIgnore]`. Upon `consol.log(fooViewModel)` inspection it is clear that there is an array of `Foo`, however, there is no associated array of `Bar` in any of the `Foos`.

Is there a way that I can skip this `[ScriptIgnore]` tag just the one time? I realize that if it skipped every time then the serializer would serialize Foo, look and see a collection of type Bar, serialize each Bar, notice that Bar had an associated Foo, serialize Foo, notice that Foo had a collection of type  Bar...etc. I only want to grab the collection of `Bar` the first time. Is there any way to accomplish this? I realize it will try to serialize `Foo` from Bar, but it will be empty. This is all done with eager loading and the entire object graph is already constructed.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this, what I ended up doing was replacing the serializer with the Json.NET serializer, which has settings, specifically

```
_jsonSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

> Json.NET will ignore objects in reference loops and not serialize them. The first time an object is encountered it will be serialized as usual but if the object is encountered as a child object of itself the serializer will skip serializing it.

The info for the settings is http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm
and I used http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx
to replace the serializer, and then I add it as default to the global.asax.cs.

```
configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings));
```

I realize this is a workaround (not actually dealing with scriptignore), however, I had so many circular references from the supplied database, that it seemed to be the best solution at the time.

Comment: Not sure if I will go this route, but thanks for providing a workaround.